# How to open specified profile Firefox with Selenium 2 Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium

When I use default profile starts without problem. But when i starts with custom profile, firefox starts but stays "blocked". The process remains active consuming 31MB of RAM, but never start. Only start if I killed the process, then starts and works fine with selenium.

I use Windows 7, Firefox 25.0.1 and selenium-server-standalone-2.38.0.jar ¿Maybe problems with compatibility of versions?

This is the code to open the profile:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(new File("C:/Users/UserTest/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/tydtn9km.testprofile"));                  
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

---

Edit:
This is my actual code

```
package org.openqa.selenium.example;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;

public class Main  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
        FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.getProfile("Other");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
        driver.get("http://google.com");
    }
}
```

**Edit 2: Resolved**
The problem ocurred because my Firefox profile is located in another partition, and Firefox in the other partition.

Answer (score 5):

I have been using it like this:

First, create a Firefox profile and name it somehow you know. E.g. `SELENIUM`

Then initialize your profile:

```
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.getProfile("SELENIUM");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
```

Comment: exactly what I do. +1

Comment: That's better than my code, but not solve my problem. I'm still having the same problem. Also in Fedora 19, but in Fedora open first the anonymous profile and a seconds after the correct profile working fine.

Comment: In that case something must be wrong either with your code (high probability) or in Fedora (low probability

Comment: I don't think the problem is my code. I updated the question with the code