# How to handle the browser notification popup in selenium using java?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I want to handle the notification popup in jabong website using selenium.

Comment: Do you want to disable push notifications from this site or from all?

Comment: @alecxe i want to disable from this website as well as when selenium script execution.

Comment: @tsivarajan if you just want to dismiss the window clicking anywhere on the page that isn't the notification will make it go away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*You cannot control this kind of "popup" via Selenium directly.*

What you can do is to:

- *disable all push notifications* for the browser session entirely:

  ```
  FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
  ffprofile.setPreference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", false);
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
  ```
- load the existing profile in which you had pre-set up the desired behavior for the push notifications for this site:

  - manually open `jabong.com` and choose the desired push notification value
  - go to Help->Troubleshooting Information
  - open the "Profile Folder" and copy path to it (or its name)
  - [load this profile when starting selenium driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543013/how-to-open-specified-profile-firefox-with-selenium-2-webdriver)

FYI, when you configure push notifications in the browser, Firefox inserts/updates a site-specific record inside `permissions.sqlite` SQLite database file which you can find inside the profile directory.